# Where should I place my context for the forms_as.p to work properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

basically, i'm trying to form.as_p to list the values but its not working. Its not really that its not working, but it only works (it only appears in my template) after i press submit. I believe I have placed the context in the wrong place or the wrong indentation but im not sure where i should shift `context['form'] = form` to. I tried to shift it but it says that lcoal variable referenced before assignment. Could someone advise?

The reason why I put it below else is because i want to display the errors if there are errors

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj= form.save(commit = False)
            author = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            obj.author = author
            obj.save()
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    form = CreateBlogPostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj= form.save(commit = False)
            author = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            obj.author = author
            obj.save()
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
        else:
            context['form'] = form
    context['form'] = form

    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your if statement, you need to add:

```
form = CreateBlogPostForm()
context['form'] = form
```

This will initialise a blank form and add it to your context.

Currently, you are only adding 'form' to your context, if the form has been submitted (/ a POST request has been sent to the view) and the form has validation errors.

To avoid repeated code, better still would be something like this:

```
def create_blog_view(request):
    user = request.user
    form = CreateBlogPostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateBlogPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj= form.save(commit = False)
            author = Account.objects.filter(email=user.email).first()
            obj.author = author
            obj.save()
            return redirect('HomeFeed:main')
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/create_blog.html", context)
```

Comment: hi are you referring to the first or the second if statement?

Comment: The first one, sorry about that! I have updated my answer to illustrate this and show a neater solution.

Comment: I cant do it your way, because the purpose of the else statement if for me to show the errors

Comment: if I were to shift my context out of the else statement, the errors wont be shown

Comment: let me know if you need my template code that displays the errors @Ffion but i doubt you'll need it

Comment: That's not true, when you assign the request.POST and request.FILES to the form, the errors (if any) will be included there. The last line context['form']... will be executed if the form is valid or not. Have a go and let me know what happens.

Comment: but nevertheless I now have 2 ` context['form'] = form` in my code and not it works

Comment: one is within the else clause and the other is in your answer

Comment: Thanks for trying it before replying. Please could you post your updated view code in your question, underneath the original so I can take a look?

Comment: Ok, thanks, now I would like to see your HTML, if you could add that too please? I can't tell what's wrong from the view (although I might be missing something)

Comment: Sure, I’ll add that in tomorrow :) could you check out this question too @Ffion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980665/how-to-set-placeholders-in-django-filters-for-fields-in-meta