# How to set placeholders in django filters for fields in meta

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to set placeholders in django filters for fields in meta. Because for the field 'type, I already have predefined specific values for them to filter, so I cant use CharFilters etc like what I did for my end_date. Any idea?

Ya so basically also because the values are PREDEFINED for ppl to select, so even if I have placeholders it will appear as '-----' How may i retify that with a custom self-made placeholder?

```
class TypeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    end_date = DateFilter(field_name="date_published", lookup_expr='lte', widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'MM/DD/YYYY'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ['type']
        
        widgets = {
        'type' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'choose type'}),
        }
```